# Can't match /*/xxx in Spring ResourceHandlerRegistry?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm try to make the following URLs resolve to the same resources on my server:

```
http://myhost/website/content/css/theme.css
http://myhost/subsite/app/website/content/css/theme.css
```

and generically:

```
http://myhost/{any non-/ string}/app/website/content/css/theme.css
```

The following config successfully resolves:

```
http://myhost/website/content/css/theme.css
```

but stubbornly refused to resolve any  */app URLs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  override def addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry): Unit = {
    // servlet context URL path pattern --> webapp_relative_path
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/website/**").addResourceLocations("/website/")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("/index.html")

    // subsite redirects
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*/app/index.html").addResourceLocations("/index.html")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*/app/website/**").addResourceLocations("/website/")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*/app/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*/app/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/")
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*/app/**").addResourceLocations("/")
  }
```

What's up with that?

NB.

- The servlet context is ROOT (/).
- All content is in /src/main/webapp/  (ie. /src/main/webapp/website/content/css/theme.css exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found that this seems to be due to a bad implementation of ant-style pattern matching in Spring, where preceding '/' don't work.

Try this:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("*/app/**").addResourceLocations("/")
```

Find my full answer in:

[Spring boot static resources mapping ant matchers with ResourceHandlerRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024861/spring-boot-static-resources-mapping-ant-matchers-with-resourcehandlerregistry/38714022#38714022)