# Spring boot static resources mapping ant matchers with ResourceHandlerRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 1.3.3
My application resources exist under **src/main/resources/static** 
example: **src/main/resources/static/index.html**
I am trying to map my static resources with a prefix like 
/*/resource/**
So that it matches urls like
/main/resource/** AND
/app/resource/**

When I try that using following code

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*/resource/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

**It comes up with a 404 when I request for domain:8080/app/resource/index.html**

But returns requested page when I do **domain:8080/index.html**
(It looked like some default matchers are overriding the ones that I tried to configured.)

And when I use the following code

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/app/resource/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
}
```

**It returns the page domain:8080/app/resource/index.html** as expected.

Is something wrong with the ant matchers I am using above? 
Can I use static resources in the way I want?

Any help is appreciated ..

Comment: See the related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632175/how-to-change-the-way-spring-boot-serves-static-files/35632734#35632734 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968479/spring-boot-cannot-find-index-html-under-webapp-folder

Comment: Those aren't helpful, as my case is different. I want /{myVar}/resources matcher. myVar is injected at runtime. Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and found the solution.

According to the 'Spring Boot Cookbook', the ResourceHandlerRegistry uses ant-style patterns. Furthermore I came across '[Spring: Difference of /** and /* with regards to paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569308/spring-difference-of-and-with-regards-to-paths)', where Devabc points out that ..

> Note that Springs' AntPathMatcher contains bugs: it isn't fully
>   conform the Ant Pattern Style. Example:
>   **/*.css won't work for paths that start with a /, while it should according to Ant Style
>   conventions. – Devabc Jun 12 '15 at 9:52

In order to match urls like http://localhost:8080/frontend/13/style.css, where 13 can vary try this:

```
/* This did NOT work */
registry.addResourceHandler("/frontend/{id:[0-9]+}/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/web-app/dist/");

/* This DID work, when removing the preceeding / */
registry.addResourceHandler("frontend/{id:[0-9]+}/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/web-app/dist/");
```

So for you this will mean: Try removing the preceding '/' in the url, i.e.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("*/resource/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
```

Comment: The problem is ResourceHadler considers everything before an * OR ** as a prefix. So, when a pattern starts with an * prefix is empty.